# Why do I have a RunTime error for my Python code?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, max, min

I am doing the Hackerrank basic Python programming challenges. This one is called **Mini-Max Sum*** and the link for the problem is: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-week-preparation-kit-mini-max-sum/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-day-one

I was able to have my code compile for the sample cases, but it does not work for any of the other cases. I am very confused as to why I receive a Run Time Error. Please help!

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'miniMaxSum' function below.
#
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
#

def miniMaxSum(arr):
    
    # Find the minimum number:   
    minimum = 10^9
    for integer in arr:
        if integer < minimum:
            minimum = integer

            
    # Search the list to find the minimum and remove it:
    arr.remove(minimum)
    
    
    # Sum all of the entries in the array; this gives the maximum sum for four integers:
    max_sum = 0
    for number in arr:
        max_sum += number
# --------------------------------------------------------
    arr.append(minimum)
        
    # Find the maximum number:
    
    maximum = 1
    for integer in arr:
        if integer > maximum:
            maximum = integer
             
    
    # Search the list to find the maximum and remove it:
    arr.remove(maximum)
    
    # Sum all of the entries in the array; this gives the maximum sum for four integers:
    min_sum = 0
    for number in arr:
        min_sum += number
        
    print(min_sum, max_sum)
    
    
           

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    miniMaxSum(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in first line of function `miniMaxSum()`.

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    
    # Find the minimum number:   
    minimum = 10^9
```

`^` denotes the [xor operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) not power/exponentiation. Use `**` in python instead.

`10^9 = 3` (in binary `1010 ^ 1001 = 0011`). Hence you initialize `minimum` with 3 instead of 1000,000,000

Why do you get Runtime error then?

```
arr.remove(minimum)
```

`minimum` = 3 may not exist in `arr`.

---

Your link to problem has expired, prefer including the statement. Current link to problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem

Statement:

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that
> can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then
> print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of
> two space-separated long integers.

Comment: Thank you so much tuhinspatra! You explained it very well to my understanding, and I appreciate your help. :)
I gave you a checkmark as a great answer!